# Cannot read properties of undefined pathname in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
import React from 'react'
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Product = ({ product }) => {
  return (
    <div>
        <Card className='my-3 p-3 rounded'>
            <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`} >
              <Card.Img src={product.image} variant="top"/>
            </Link>
        </Card>
        <Card.Body>
          <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
            <Card.Title as="div">{product.name}</Card.Title>
          </Link>
        </Card.Body>
        <Card.Text as="h3">{product.price}</Card.Text>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Product
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Link to={`/product/${product?._id}`} >
              <Card.Img src={product?.image} variant="top"/>
 </Link>
//some code
 <Link to={`/product/${product?._id}`}>
            <Card.Title as="div">{product?.name}</Card.Title>
 </Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can reproduce this specific error, in either of `react-router-dom` v5 and v6, is to use the low-level `Router` component without passing the appropriate required props.

- `react-router-dom@5` `Router` requires a `history` prop.
- `react-router-dom@6` `Router` requires `location` and `navigator` props.

Either provide the appropriate props or use the appropriate high-level routers, i.e. `BrowserRouter`, `MemoryRouter`, `HashRouter`, etc...

Example, import the `BrowserRouter` and rename to `Router` so the exited code works as expected.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
```

[image: Edit cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-pathname-in-react]